# I am unable to secure a WPA handshake (4 way handshake)

Tags: wpa2, aircrack-ng

I am training to be a pen tester and am having some issues obtaining a 4 way handshake. I use `airodump-ng -c -w file --bssid wlo1` followed by `Aireplay-ng -0 0 -a (Mac) wlo1`

Here's all the steps I follow:

```
Ifconfig wlo1
ifconfig wlo1 down
iwconfig wlo1 mode monitor
ifconfig wlo1 up
airmon-ng check wlo1
kill processes

Airodump-ng wlo1
airodump-ng -c (channel) -w (file) --bssid  wlo1 
aireplay-ng -0 0 -a (mac) wlo1
```

I know what to do after I get the handshake, I am just stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using Fedora 25

Comment: I tried to keep my code nice and neat but it seems to smash it all together. I can send a screenshot if anyone is confused. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First you have to make sure that your NIC can inject and that the targeted access point is in range.

```
aireplay-ng -9 wlo1
```

After running this command you should see 'Injection is working!' , and the targeted AP with a high response rate ( 50 - 100% )

Deauthentication attack sends disassocate packets to connected clients, so you need to have at least one associated client.

```
airodump-ng -c <ap channel> --bssid <ap mac> wlo1
```

There should be at least one MAC under the 'STATION' tab associated with the AP. You can use this client for a targeted attack.

```
aireplay-ng -0 5 -a <ap mac> -c <client mac> wlo1
```

You may have to run the above command several times untill you get a handshake.

You can increase or decrease the number of deauthentication packets. Sometimes one is enough, sometimes it takes ten or more. If you still can't capture a WPA handshake then maybe the issue is with your NIC. Here you'll find a list of [compatible drivers](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers), and a [patching guide](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=patching).

Comment: When I run that injection test I see where it is attempting to broadcast probe requests. After that there's "no answer". It comes back saying found 6 APs but they all come back at 0%. Is there a driver I can download or do I need to get an external wireless card?

Comment: That means that your interface can't inject. Are you sure it's `wlo1` and not `mon0` or `wlo1mon` ? If you run `airmon-ng start wlo1` you will see "monitor mode is enabled on ..." . Use that interface. If you still can't inject, here you'll find a list of compatible drivers : [compatibility_drivers](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers) , and a patching guide : [patching](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=patching)

Comment: Yeah it's definitely wlo1. I can see that it's in monitor mode once I switch from promiscuous mode. Thanks for the drivers guide, I really appreciate it!!

Comment: Turns out my wireless card is not compatible so I ordered the Alfa-AWUS036H-802-11b-Wireless-network/dp/B002WCEWU8. Thanks for your help